# move folders recursively using find

Tags: ubuntu, bash, find, move

Please see the below issue. Actually I wanted to move only 20022021 folder (which cotains subdir and files) to the destination, But its moving both the directories.

```
nasa:/# find /tmp/source -mindepth 1 -mtime -1 -exec mv -t /tmp/destination/ {} \;
find: ‘/tmp/source/20022021’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/tmp/source/21022021’: No such file or directory
nasa:/# cd /tmp/destination/
nasa:/tmp/destination/# ls
20022021  21022021
nasa:/tmp/destination# ls -lrt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 20 13:27 20022021
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 21 06:35 21022021
```

I tried with -mtime +1 but its not moving any of the directories and it stays in the source itself. Please suggest me whats the problem here is

```
nasa:/# find /tmp/source -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -exec mv -t /tmp/destination/ {} \;
nasa:/# cd /tmp/source
nasa:/tmp/source# ls
20022021  21022021
nasa:/tmp/source# ls -lrt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 20 13:27 20022021
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 21 06:35 21022021
nasa:/# cd /tmp/destination/
nasa:/tmp/destination/# ls -lrt
total 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see your issue if you change `-exec` to  `-exec echo`, this will print the commands you are running. The error message is because you are scanning into sub-directories of folders like `/tmp/source/20022021` that you've already moved:

```
 find: ‘/tmp/source/20022021’: No such file or directory
```

Fix by using `find -maxdepth 1` so that once the top level folder is checked, it's sub-directories are not scanned / moved later, or if you want to scan sub-directories, append `-prune` to the end of the line so that if a top level directory is not moved, find will go into sub-directories.

```
find /tmp/source -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -exec mv -t /tmp/destination/ {} \;

find /tmp/source -mindepth 1 -mtime -1 -exec mv -t /tmp/destination/ {} \; -prune
```